# Vote to delete before question is closed

Tags: feature-request

Often times, I will vote to close an obviously awful question, with the full intent of returning to delete it once it is closed.  This is pain however, as I find myself continually coming back to that tab, and refreshing the page to see if the question has been finally closed yet.

I would love to be able to go ahead and cast a delete vote, contingent on the fact that the question will be closed.

Comment: A question shouldn't be deleted (except by owner) if it's not even closed...

Comment: I believe Jonathon is aware of that, and only wants to cast a "queued" delete vote, which would only take effect when the question is closed. Jonathon, would you be okay with these "queued" votes being discarded if the question is edited, before or after closure?

Comment: That's a hard sell.  Consider asking for making the Triage queue's "unsalvageable" more universal.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I could see some issues with doing that.  Do queued votes count against my daily limit or not until they are actually applied?  What happens if you cross over start of day with pending stuff in the queue?

Comment: @Nathan, you're right there are some edge cases here. I would be conservative and say queued votes should immediately count against your quota, be they discarded later or not.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I think the most conservative approach would be acceptable. I'm talking really, really bad questions that are obviously going to be closed.

Answer (score -9):

IMHO I would prefer not to delete the question (except by owner).
When possible it's always better to help to improve the question's quality.

Comment: It is usually impossible to improve an "obviously awful question".

Comment: When the # of "awful" questions outnumber the # of users 100 to 1, it isn't possible to improve all of them.

Comment: You're optimistic because you've only been editing posts for a few days. Cherish this time before you become a grumpy regular like many of us.

Comment: I would like to think that the owner always tries to improve its own questions, but maybe it's really an optimistic view :)

Comment: @FilipePinto It's a super optimistic view- There are tons of times when you can tell the OP exactly what they're missing to be able to get an answer, and instead they'll either get mad at you for it or make up some excuse for why they can't add whatever you're requesting. Kudos for trying to help out, though. Keep it up.